# unify multiple fields with the same ID into one field SQL Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have these data, which look like this:

```
   ID      name
------------------
   1       Judith
   1       John
   1       Tim
   2       Anna
   2       Tyler
```

And I need to unify that table, having an output like this:

```
   ID      name
-------------------------------
   1       Judith, John, Tim
   2       Anna, Tyler
```

How can I do a Linq query in C# to get that result? (Or at least in SQL...)

Thank you!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some products have their own SQL functionality for this.)

Answer (score 0):

in T-SQL you can use STRING_AGG

```
select id, STRING_AGG(name,',') 
from users GROUP BY id
```

Here's a sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5bb27/2